# Why am I getting different answers for variance depending on the method I choose to find it?

Tags: probability

[image]

**The weird "a" symbol in the question is supposed to be summation. Sorry for that error, the question is poorly worded. It's supposed to be X = X_i/50 from i =1 to i = 50. Same thing applies for the Y variable**

In the above question, I know how to find the expectation of X and Y. For example, for E[X] (where X = (1/50)(X1+X2+X3+...+X_50)

E[(1/50)(X1+X2+X3+X4+...+X_50)]
= (1/50)*E[X1+X2+X3+X4+...+X_50]
= (1/50)*( E[X1] + E[X2] + ...+E[X_50])

The formula to find expectation of exponential distribution is 1/λ. Hence,

**E[X] = (1/50)*50(1/.5) = 2**

For exponential distirbution, variance is (E[X])^2, so Var(X) is 4. **BUT**, when I try to find Var(X)---and Var(Y)---using the properties of variance I get a different answer:

Var[X] = Var[(1/50)(X1+X2+X3...+X_50)] = (1/50)^2 *  Var[X1+X2+X3+...+X_50] = (1/50)^2 * (Var[X1] + Var[X2] + Var[X3] + ... + Var[X_50]) = (1/50)^2 * 50 * (1/.5^2) = .08

As you can see, when I directly use the formula for variance of exponential function, I get 4, but when I do it using the property Var[k * X] = k^2 * Var[X] (where "k" is an arbitrary constant), I get a different answer.

Below is the solution I was provided. Is it wrong? Here, they just square E[X] and E[Y] to get Variance:

[image]

Comment: What does the big $a$ mean in the formula for $X$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "a" represents a constant

Comment: David, writing ${a_1^\circ}^{50}$ or whatever doesn't make sense if $a$ is a constant. Is this supposed to be summation or something?

Comment: thats a property of variance..if you have a constant, you can take it out of the Var[x] and you square it

Comment: I think $\dot{a}$ is just a unicode rendering error for $\sum$.

Comment: David. You are not paying attention.  In the png you posted I see $X = {a^\circ}_1^{50} X_i / 50$.  Please explain what this means or fix it.

Comment: There are two $a$-s here. There's the giant $\large a$ in the image, and then there's the $a$ at the bottom of OP's answer. It's clear from OP's calculations that they realize the giant $\large a$ is a typo for $\sum$, but at the bottom they use the letter $a$ as an arbitrary constant in the formula $\text{Var}(aX)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$. That's where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: sorry for the confusion..i fixed it

Comment: @David If you have any question to my answer, feel free to ask.

Comment: That property is a generic property. Here "X" is the sum of X1+X2+...X_50. I dont think it means the property is invalid. The variance of sums is sum of variance if the variables are independent.

Comment: @David But at the forumula $Var(aX)$ the random variable $X$ is not independent from $X$. The expression $aX$ means that one random variable is multiplied by a constant $a$. In your case you have a sum of 50 independent random variables which do not depend on each other.

Comment: @David But what is your further question referring to the solution? Anyway you should first understand what I have posted. It is one of a key concepts in statistics. Step by step...

Comment: is the sum of exponential distributions an exponential distribution? Because if its not, as Jack M says, then it doesnt make sense to use the variance formula for exponential function for calculating Var(X)

Comment: @David It is not important if the sum is exponentially distributed or not. The important thing is that the variables are *identical and independent*. In this case the following equation holds: $Var(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Var(X_i)$

Comment: @David I´m offline for the next hours. I have to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Your second answer is correct. The formula $\text{Var}(\overline X_n)=\frac1n\text{Var}(X_1)$ is always correct when the $X_i$ are iid (and of finite variance).

The problem is with your first method. The logic is basically this.

1. If $X=\frac1{50}\sum X_i$, then $E(X)=E(X_1)=2$.
2. The variance of an exponentially distributed random variable is the square of its expected value.
3. Therefore $\text{Var}(X)=E(X)^2=4$.

The problem is that in step $3$, you're applying the rule in step $2$ to the variable $X$, not to the $X_i$. And even though the $X_i$ are exponentially distributed, $X$ is not. The sum of iid exponentially distributed random variables follows a Gamma distribution, not exponential.

Comment: What you said makes sense..but the solution I have for this just squares E[X]..i'm so confused

Comment: @David Does the solution say the variance of $X$ is $4$?

Comment: i posted the solution...there they just have 4..but these solutions could have errors (its not from a textbook or anything..i think my teacher wrote it out)

Comment: @David Um... I don't want to judge without having all the facts, but I think your teacher might not really know what the hell they're talking about. $X$ and $Y$ are not exponentially distributed, so this logic is not justified. Even if we're generous and assume they really mean $X_i$ and $Y_i$ in that solution, the variance of $Z$ is definitely not $10.25$; I haven't done the calculation but computer simulation shows it's around $0.23$. Furthermore, in the next step, we're not really justified in assuming $Z$ is normally distributed, since $X$ and $Y$ are differently distributed.

Comment: Z is approximately normally distributed because of central limit theorem. Sum of iid is approximately normal if n > 30. That part makes sense to me.

Comment: @David But $Z$ isn't a sum of iid variables, it's a sum of $50$ iid variables with one distribution and $40$ iid variables with a different distribution. Well, alright, I suppose you can argue that $X$ and $Y$ are each normally distributed by CLT and then say $Z$ is the sum of two normals.

Comment: Yea, X and Y are each approximately normal, and we know the sum of normal distr is normal

Comment: @David Now I understand where the $10.25$ comes from - your teacher applied additivity of variance to the (wrong) variances of $X$ and $Y$, $4$ and $6.25$. So other than the mistake of thinking $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed, the solution is fine. You should mention that to your teacher, I'm sure they'll be grateful for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Let´s say that the random variables $X_i$ are independent and identical distributed. Then

$Var\left( \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(X_i)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot n\cdot Var(X_i)=\frac{Var(X_i)}{n}$

In your case we have $Var\left( \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i\right)=\frac{Var(X_i)}{50}=\frac{\frac1{0.5^2}}{50}=\frac{4}{50}=0.08$

I agree with your result.

> As you can see, when I directly use the formula for variance of
>   exponential function, I get 4, but when I do it using the property
>   $Var[k * X] = k^2 * Var[X]$ (where "$k$" is an arbitrary constant), I get
>   a different answer.

The formula $Var(a\cdot X)=a^2\cdot Var(X)$ is the formula where you have only one variable X. This variable $X$ does fully depend on itsself.Let's see how it works if $a=2$.

$Var(2X)=Var(X)+Var(X)+2\cdot Cov(X,X)$. We know that $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$. Thus

$Var(2X)=Var(X)+Var(X)+2Var(X)$

$Var(2X)=4Var(X)$

But this works only for **one** variable $X$ which has been multiplied by a constant.

Comment: But we do only have one variable. Namely, $\sum X_i$.

Comment: You sum n different variables. That´s the key point.

Comment: The result of which is another variable which we call $X$ and apply the formula.

Comment: Please notice $Cov(X_i,X_j)=0$ if the random variables are independent. This is different from $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$

Comment: Sorry, but now that I've found the actual error in OP's logic, I have to say this answer really makes no sense. You seem to be claiming that the formula $\text{Var}(aX)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$ somehow magically stops working when $X$ is a sum of other random variables. Every variable $X$ is a sum of other random variables. For example it's the sum $X+0$, or $X/2 + X/2$. A variable is a variable, it doesn't matter what kind of formula you write it down with.

Comment: @JackM The difference is between the variance of  $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ (identically and independent) and the variance of $n\cdot X$. At the first case you have $n$ identically and independent variables and at the second case you have $n$ times the variable  $X$. The cases are different.

Comment: Are you saying that $\text{Var}(\sum X_i)=\sum \text{Var}(X_i)$ is only valid when the $X_i$ are independent? That's true, but OP never implied otherwise.

Comment: @JackM The intention of the post was to answer the question he have asked. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{50}$ be a random sample from $\mathsf{Exp}(rate = \lambda_X = 0.5).$ This distribution has $\mu_X =E(X_i) = 1/\lambda_X = 1/0.5 = 2$ and $\sigma_X^2 = Var(X_i) = (1/\lambda_X)^2 = 4.$

Let $\bar X = \frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i.$ Then $E(\bar X) = \mu_X = 2$ and
$Var(\bar X) = \sigma_X^2/50 = 4/50 = 0.08.$ Another approach is to note that
$\bar X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(shape = 50, rate = 50\lambda_X),$ so that
$E(\bar X) = \frac{50}{50\lambda_X} = \mu_X = 2$ and
$Var(\bar X) = \frac{50}{(50\lambda_X)2} = 4/50 = 0.08.$

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_{40}$ be a random sample from $\mathsf{Exp}(rate = \lambda_Y = 0.4).$ This distribution has $\mu_Y =E(Y_i) = 1/\lambda_Y = 1/0.4 = 2.5$ and $\sigma_Y^2 = Var(Y_i) = (1/\lambda_Y)^2 = 6.25.$

Let $\bar Y = \frac{1}{40}\sum_{i=1}^{40} Y_i.$ Then $E(\bar Y) = \mu_Y = 2.5$ and
$Var(\bar Y) = \sigma_Y^2/40 = 6.25/40 = 0.15625.$ [Again here, an argument in
terms of $\bar Y \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(40, 40\lambda_Y)$ can be made to show
the same results for $E(\bar Y)$ and $Var(\bar Y).$]

---

*Note:* Using R statistical software, these results can be illustrated (correct to several decimal places) by
simulating a million samples of size 50 from $\mathsf{Exp}(rate = \lambda_X = 0.5),$ and finding a million sample means $\bar X.$ Similarly for the $\bar Y.$

```
x.bar = replicate(10^6, mean(rexp(50, .5)))
mean(x.bar); var(x.bar)
## 1.99928      # aprx E(samp mean) = 2
## 0.07970933   # aprx Var(samp mean) = 0.08

y.bar = replicate(10^6, mean(rexp(40, .4)))
mean(y.bar); var(y.bar)
## 2.500118     # aprx 2.5
## 0.1563497    # aprx 0.15625
```

The figure below shows histograms of simulated distributions of $\bar X$ and $\bar Y,$ along with the respective density functions of $\mathsf{Gamma}(50,25)$
and $\mathsf{Gamma}(40,16).$

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  hist(x.bar, prob=T, br = 50, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Simulated Dist'n of X-bar with Gamma Density")
    curve(dgamma(x, 50, 25), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
  hist(y.bar, prob=T, br = 50, col="skyblue2", 
      main="Simulated Dist'n of Y-bar with Gamma Density")
    curve(dgamma(x, 40, 16), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: You did not explicitly ask about the random variable $Z$ at the end of the printed problem: It is not easy to find the exact distribution of $Z = \bar X + \bar Y.$ (The sum of two gamma random variables is not gamma, unless the rates are equal.) However, as you can see from the illustration both $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ are nearly normal; add the means and variances to get a normal approximation of $Z$ and thus to approximate $P(Z < 5),$ which by simulation is about 0.848.

Comment: ok so the solutions is wrong right? For the variance of X and Y, that is. In the solutions he made the assumption that X and Y were also exponential, when in fact they're gamma distribution

Comment: Yes, there are errors in the handwritten part of your Question. Tried to use standard statistical notation and formulas you can find elsewhere online and on this site.